# How to use DISALLOW_FACTORY_RESET in my app?

Tags: android

There is a field, called DISALLOW_FACTORY_RESET, which can be found in the official Android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html#DISALLOW_FACTORY_RESET).

But how to use it?

Or are there any other ways for an app to block the factory reset option? (even if it needs root/device admin permissions)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way-

Just add a reciever in your manifest-:

```
<receiver android:name=".app.DeviceAdminSample$DeviceAdminSampleReceiver"
            android:label="@string/sample_device_admin"
            android:description="@string/sample_device_admin_description"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin_sample" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DISALLOW_FACTORY_RESET" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks! It just blocks the option of Factory Reset from Settings App, right?
 But that does not prevent user from turning the device into Factory Mode and performing a Factory Reset from there, right?